# Ethereum Transaction Using cUrl and web3.php, I get a Receipt but the Transaction is not sent to the Network

Tags: php, sendrawtransaction

This has been doing my head in all day, after wading through and managing to get all my values converted to hex I create and sign the ethereum transaction using the web3p/ethereum-tx library from GitHub. I put in the cUrl request with the parameters to the infura mainet. I get a response with a transaction hash but when I search for it on etherscan and others it does not show up, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3p\EthereumTx\Transaction;

$balance = bcdiv($balanceInWei, "1000000000000000000", 18);
$gasTotal = 4000000000 * 21004;
$value = bcsub($balanceInWei, $gasTotal);
$gas = dechex(21004);
$gasPrice = dechex(4000000000);

function bcdechex($dec) {
$hex = '';
do {    
$last = bcmod($dec, 16);
$hex = dechex($last).$hex;
$dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
} while($dec>0);
return $hex;
}

$hexValue = bcdechex($value);
$nonce = time();
$hexNonce = dechex($nonce);

echo $wallet_address;
  // with chainId
  $transaction = new Transaction([
      'nonce' => '0x'.$hexNonce,
      'from' => $wallet_address,
      'to' => '0xMyWalletAddress',
      'gas' => '0x'.$gas,
      'gasPrice' => '0x'.$gasPrice,
      'value' => '0x'.$hexValue,
      'chainId' => 1,
      'data' => '0x0'
  ]);
  $signedTransaction = $transaction->sign($databaseContainer->private_key);

  $url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MyApiKey";
  $data = array(
          "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
          "method" => "eth_sendRawTransaction",
          "params" => array("0x".$signedTransaction),
          "id" => 1
  );
  $json_encoded_data = json_encode($data);

  var_dump($json_encoded_data);

  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_encoded_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_encoded_data))
  );

  $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
  dd($result);
```

dd is just me dumping the result in larvel. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Same here**, any thoughts !! Any thoughts, transaction hash not show up in https://etherscan.io/, for verification ??

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that your nonce is not right. Nonce should be an incrementing transaction counter, not derives from unixtimestamp. Also it seems you are missing gasLimit parameter?